# using volley and post method - php

Tags: php, android

I made an `index.php` file and content of it is :

```
<?php
ini_set('default_charset',"UTF-8");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8') ;

//-----------vitrinsaz-----------

if(isset($_POST['get_job_service_category'])){
//    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
//    $object = new DB_Functions();
 //   echo json_encode($object->getJobServiceCategory());

echo "test";

}


}?>
```

I want to use `get_job_service_category` key in volley lib and it must return test :

```
private void getAllCategories(){

    RequestQueue queue = MyVolley.getRequestQueue();

    StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            TagsClass.URL_ADDRESS,
            createMyReqSuccessListener(),
            createMyReqErrorListener()) {

        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("get_job_service_category","-");
            return params;
        };
    };
    queue.add(myReq);

}

private Response.Listener<String> createMyReqSuccessListener() {
    return new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            parseResultOfServer(response.toString());
        }
    };
}

private void parseResultOfServer(String str){

    Log.e("sss", "=>" + str);

}

private Response.ErrorListener createMyReqErrorListener() {
    return new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("err","="+error.getMessage());

        }
    };
}
```

But it doesn't returns any value ! where is my wrong ?

My `index.php` address :

http://www.shadyab.com/Mobile/vitrin/index.php

**updated :**

```
var_dump($_POST);

if(isset($_POST['get_job_service_category'])){
//    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
//    $object = new DB_Functions();
   // echo 'json_encode($object->getJobServiceCategory())';

    echo "test";

}
```

it returns :

```
array(0) { }
```

Comment: Could you run `var_dump($_POST);` in your PHP script and post the result?

Comment: inside if statement or above it ?

Comment: Put the statement above it.

Comment: updated my question .

Comment: when I use it inside if statement, it not returns anythings.

Comment: This needs to be picked up by somebody on the android side. Your request isn't being sent properly.

Comment: as far as your android code is considered it looks fine.

Answer (score 1):

> **var_dump()** : This function displays structured information about one or more expressions that includes its type and value.

Taken from [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

As in you case right now, you are not providing any parameter(in POST) to `index.php` it is showing you following response :

> array(0) {
>   }

But as soon as you provide, `get_job_service_category` as parameter to `index.php`, it will provide you following response :

> array(1) {
>
> [get_job_service_category]=>
>
> string(0) ""
>
> }
>
> test

For passing $_POST a value of particular tag use Awesome Chrome Plugin : [www.getpostman.com](http://www.getpostman.com) for testing out your API's.

[image: Post Man]

**Edit 1:** If you remove `var_dump($_POST);` from your `index.php`, you will get simple response as

> test

Comment: I installed this extension, but it returns `array(0) { }` for me.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian are doing the same way as displayed in picture. Selecting POST from Dropdown. And if you remove `var_dump($_POST);` It will show you blank response if no post parameter is provided otherwise "test" will be displayed.

Comment: I expected to sew  "test ". my code : `if(isset($_POST['get_job_service_category'])){
    echo "test";
}`

Comment: yes right you have removed `var_dump()` from your php, and i am getting "test" as a response